# How do you execute code from another file in an if statement?

Tags: python, file, connection

I have a project, that I am working on with only one file (main.py) and the code just gets really messy with lots and lots of if statements and things, so I can make new files, but how do I get the `main.py` file to execute the code in another file? Here is an example:

```
if condition:
  execute code in another file
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code in the other file is organized into a function, you can import it and call it:

```
from othermodule import otherfunction

if condition:
    otherfunction()
```

Comment: What if I just want to execute _all_ the code in the file? Instead of having to make it into a function. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes its possible, depending on how the module is organized.  Simply importing a module will execute all of the top-level statements in that module (i.e. any code that isn't inside a function or a class.)  So if a module has _only_ top-level statements, then importing it will run all the code.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use funtions inside other files you can use

```py
from otherFile import someFunction
```

or

```py
from otherFile import *
```

`otherFile` has to be replaced with the name of the python file without the `.py`

**Edit**: `import *` imports every function inside the file

Comment: What does the star represent?

Comment: @RedSox2 it means "import everything".